# How to make fields available to users in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, field

I want users to participate in creating some content. I allowed them (people/permissions) to create own content on particular content type. The question is: how to provide them access to fields of content type, that are available to me as administrator? In other words, I can put content in fields through my admin panel, but how to make users possible to meet that fields, how to make fields public?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fields permissions module. This will allow you to set field level permissions in Drupal 6 and 7
https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions

Comment: Thanks, bit still I don't see how to display empty field box to user. It should be like webform field. One page with empty fields, that users populate with information. How to make page that displays empty fields?

Comment: Make sure they have access to the correct text format.  Sometimes if they don't have access to the default text format the field won't show.

Comment: You said:" Sometimes if they don't have access to the default text format the field won't show." But, I am asking where field should show at all? I would like to make page that displays empty fields.   
For example, as administrator I can create Content type, and if I want to add some content, I have to go to content/add content, then choose content type, and empty fields appears. My question is: how to make page that displays empty fields for users to type into? Uh, I don't know if I am clear.   I'm sorry for bothering you.

Comment: All you have to do is send the user to the same page where you are filling out the fields. For example if you want the user to create an article you would send them to http://yourdomain.com/node/add/article.  This will give them all of the fields to create an article as long as they have permission.

Comment: I am filling out the fields via admin panel. When I log in by my authenticated user account, and paste url of the page where I fill out the fields(as admin), nothing appears. And everything is ok with text format access. Please, let me ask you one more question. How would you make page with webform fields using mere fields (no webform module etc.)? Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the information.  If you want to display the information that they submit then it needs to be a node they are creating.  You say nothing appears when you go to the same url does that mean a white screen? No fields? What do you see?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34468/discussion-between-natttan-and-jsheffers)

Comment: Noo. It works! I was trying before, and it didn't. Now, it works. This was helpful. Thanks, you are really patient.